Is it possible to get txn ID in solana program?
Saying every transaction will generate a transaction ID.
We can get it after sending transaction via ts/python/rust and so on, find it in sol explorer called 'signature'(maybe other name, String length is 88).
My question is: Is it possible to get the transaction ID in solana program(use Anchor framework) while executing this program invoked by this transaction self?

To put it simply: no.
An on-chain program does not have access to the signature bytes of the executing transaction, unless it's passed in as instruction data.
I don't think you're asking this, but just to be sure: on top of that, an on-chain program cannot fetch a previous transaction.
